# Numbering items in an ActiveAdmin Report

Tags: activeadmin

Is it possible to get the sequential number of each item in ActiveAdmin?

So it would look like this:

```
| Number | Name  |

| 1      | Bill  |

| 2      | Smith |
```

I know this can be achieved with `each_with_index` but don't think there is a way to use this with ActiveAdmin.

Could something be added in as `controller do` ?

I want to add this functionality into an index on ActiveAdmin so for example

```
index do
   column "Number" do |a|
       # Some way of specifying index number         
   end
   column "Name" do |a|
       a.name
   end

end
```

Thanks

Comment: why won't you go with each_with_index, as you've mentioned?

Comment: Hey @AndreyDeineko ActiveAdmin doesn't allow this from the looks of it

Comment: may be i've got the question wrong, check the answer, and let me know, if that's what you were looking for

Comment: hey man - just tried it in my real app index do end block - table is working there. Even though you would have to work on styling things - it does the trick - what problem did you face?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is works:

```
index do
  @index = 30 * (((params[:page] || 1).to_i) - 1) # 30 needs to set to that what your page size is
  column :number do
    @index += 1
  end
end
```

UPDATE: There is a build in implementation on the [way](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/pull/4093):

```
index do
  selectable_column
  index_column
  column ...
end
```