# How to specify a column which is auto-incremented in ActiveAdmin in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I am working with ActiveAdmin in Rails 5.0, currently the data is displaying as shown in attached image:

[image]

I want to replace the **ID** column with an **auto-incremented column**,

Here is my code:

```
     index do
            id_column     // i want to replace this with auto-incremented column

            column "Job" do |review|
                review.applicant.job.title
            end

            column "Applicant" do |review|
                "#{review.applicant.profile.name}"
            end

            column :created_at

            column "Actions" do |review|
                link_to "View", admin_review_path(review)
            end
    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you want to give the auto increment serial number. If you want to add the serial no, then try the below code

```
index do
        selectable_column
        @index = 30*(((params[:page] || 1).to_i) - 1) #30 needs to set to that what your page size 
        column :number do
             @index +=1
        end

        column "Job" do |review|
            review.applicant.job.title
        end

        column "Applicant" do |review|
            "#{review.applicant.profile.name}"
        end

        column :created_at

        column "Actions" do |review|
            link_to "View", admin_review_path(review)
        end
end
```

The above code content copied from [Numbering items in an ActiveAdmin Report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27433160/numbering-items-in-an-activeadmin-report/27442789). Please refer the topic.

Comment: Copied from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27433160/numbering-items-in-an-activeadmin-report/27442789#27442789

Comment: @TimoSchilling sorry, i forgot to add the reference.

Answer (score 0):

ActiveAdmin has a DSL for that.

```
index do
  selectable_column
  index_column
  column ...
end
```

I you use a old ActiveAdmin Version you can do this: [Numbering items in an ActiveAdmin Report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27433160/numbering-items-in-an-activeadmin-report/27442789#27442789)